# select2 Cannot select new term with keyboard when no suggestions

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-select2

Cannot select new term with keyboard when no suggestionsWant to be able to add new term. The code below works perfect when there are suggestions (can scroll with the keyboard and select any).

When i run out of suggestions (new term) the only way to select it is by clicking with the mouse.
If i dont click i lose the typed term with the focus.

```
$("#lin_to_mobiles").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    width: 'resolve',
    multiple: true,
    createSearchChoice: function(term, data){ return {id:term, text:term};},
    createSearchChoicePosition: 'top',
    selectOnBlur: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "if/searchContacts.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 300,
        loadMorePadding: 300,
        data: function(term, page){
            return {
                q: term,
                page_limit: 10,
                page: page
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page){
            var more = (page * 10) < data[0].total;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                data[i].disabled = eval(data[i].disabled);
            }
            return {results: data, more: more};
        },
        formatSelection: function(data){
            return data.text;
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated